# How can I display an inline list with a fixed position?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display an inline list, with the first 5 elements pulled left, and the last 2 elements pulled right, as shown below:

[image]

This inline list needs to cling to the top of the screen when the user scrolls past it, and so I need to set `position: fixed` and `top: 0px`. However, when I try to do this, the left side of the list ends up stacking onto the right side, as shown below:

[image]

Is there any way to preserve the inline display of the list while using a fixed position? If not, what are other solutions to this issue?

Here's my code, sorry if it's a mess or not formatted correctly. I've just started playing around with web dev:

**CSS:**

```
.menu-header {
  background-color: #2658C9;
}
.menu-header .pull-left {
  margin-left: 10%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.menu-header .pull-right {
  margin-right: 10%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.menu-header ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
  display: inline;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu-header">
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="menu-header-list">
      <div class="pull-left">
        <li><a href="index.html" class="menubutton">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menubutton">Tech</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menubutton">Tutorials</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menubutton">Articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menubutton">Papers</a></li>
      </div>
      <div class="pull-right">
        <li><a href="#" class="menubutton">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menubutton">Contact</a></li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, as I've been trying to fix this for hours. Changing the display & using floats hasn't fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/450/)

```css
.navbar {
  background: #2658C9;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a{
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe that's all I had to do this whole entire time

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused because you didn't set width:100% to your header.

```
 .menu-header{
      width:100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into these CSS:

```
.menu-header {
    background-color: #2658C9;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.menu-header .pull-left {
    float:left;
}
.menu-header .pull-right {
    float:right;
}
.menu-header ul {
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.menu-header ul li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

float pull left and right and display li in inline-block

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution for you

```
.row{
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
}
```

fix your `.row` not the 'ul'

for the complete code , I have created a complete code.if you want you cant try it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>working with bootstrap offline</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">

<style type="text/css">

div.menuone ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    margin:20px;
}

div.menutwo ul li{
    ist-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    margin: 30px;

}
div.menuone ul li a, div.menutwo ul li a{
    color: white;
}

div.menuone{
    padding-top: 30px;
}

div.menutwo{
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}


</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="menu-header">
  <div class="row" style="background-color:blue;">
       <div class="col-md-8 menuone">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" class="menubutton">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menubutton">Tech</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menubutton">Tutorials</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menubutton">Articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menubutton">Papers</a></li>
        </ul> 
       </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 menutwo">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="menubutton">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menubutton">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>  



<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>



</html>
```